# how do i brute force my wallet.dat to get my private key

Tags: private-key, hash, wallet.dat, recover-private-key

i am not really a computer programmer, but i want to get my private key from my wallet.dat, i have just the wallet.dat file and the public address where the bitcion was send. From my previous researches, i was told brute force the wallet is good to use, like i said i got just the wallet.dat file, but while trying to see on how i could proceed with the brute force process, it requires a hastcat and a master key whereas i have just the .dat file.

my question are

1. how do i get the hashcat? is there a site i will go and putin some particular word to be able to get the hashcat? if yes which word?
2. how do i get the master key as well since i have just the wallet.dat and the address in which the bitcoin was send to

Comment: i can't remember the password, but i have linked the wallet.dat file to the new bitcoin core i downloaded on my new machine, windows 10 to be precise

Answer (score 2):

To bruteforce a wallet.dat file you would need to follow these steps.

1. Install python from python.org
2. Download john the ripper from github
3. run the script bitcoin2john.py to extract the hash
4. get hashcat from hashcat.net

With hashcat you can search the entire space of numbers of your choice using a mask ?d?d?d?d?d?d and increment.

Your hashcat command would look like: hashcat -m 11300 wallethash.txt -a 3 ?d?d?d?d?d?d?d --increment etc would work

Once the password is found you can use it to export the private key from core.

(From another topic, but i can help you if you have question)

Comment: You forgot to mention that it might take millennia to discover the key using brute force.

Comment: if you have no idea what the password is, it could take a lifetime. With a bit of luck, good wordlists and good settings, it can be found. 
But if you know the length, some characters or the ones used, the password can be found much easier.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Bitcoin Core:

1 - Go to window > console

2 - Type listunspent

3 - You will get a list of addresses with the spendable amount

4 - Copy one of those addresses

5 - Type dumpprivkey pasteYourAddressHere