# wallet.dat password recovey

Tags: wallet, private-key, wallet-recovery

everyone!
I forgot the password for my wallet.dat, I tried to recover it myself, I’ve been working on it for a month now, but so far without success...at the moment I got to the pywallet.py program and received the following data:
encrytped_key, nDerivationIterations, nDerivationMethod, nID, salt....
encrypted_key has a value greater than 64 characters , is it possible to get a private key from these parameters?

---

### "minversion": 60000,
"mkey": {
"encrypted_key": "approximately 100 characters in HEX format",
"nDerivationIterations": 111111,
"nDerivationMethod": 0,
"nID": 1,
"otherParams": "",
"salt": "16 characters in HEX format"
}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do i brute force my wallet.dat to get my private key](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/105978/how-do-i-brute-force-my-wallet-dat-to-get-my-private-key)